# Stepper progress bar - responsive css

Tags: css

I would like to do a responsive stepper where in the lines in between steppers are connected to each step. Currently only workable with 4 steps, it becomes not responsive once it is more or less than 4 steps.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c2vgmh7/), currently workable with 4 steps.

```
  .bullet.completed::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      height: 1px;
      width: calc(133% - 21px);
      background-color: #000;
      margin-left: 7px;  
  }
```

I tried to change this part but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for advance!

```css
#stepProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.step-text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.completed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(133% - 21px);
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 7px;  
}


/* Base styles and helper stuff */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms background-color;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="stepProgressBar">
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Super Duper Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Long Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet completed">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `.bullet.completed::after` to `display:flex`, and set its `width` to `100%` minus a modified `margin-left` value, which is equal to the width of the `.bullet` (`20px`):

```
.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  display:flex;            /* Added */
  width:calc(100% - 20px); /* Modified */
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 20px;       /* Modified */
}
```

Here it is with seven steps:

```js
const previousBtn = document.getElementById('previousBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
const finishBtn = document.getElementById('finishBtn');
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

const MAX_STEPS = 7;
let currentStep = 1;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 1].classList.add('completed');
  currentStep += 1;
  previousBtn.disabled = false;
  if (currentStep === MAX_STEPS) {
    nextBtn.disabled = true;
    finishBtn.disabled = false;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});


previousBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bullets[currentStep - 2].classList.remove('completed');
  currentStep -= 1;
  nextBtn.disabled = false;
  finishBtn.disabled = true;
  if (currentStep === 1) {
    previousBtn.disabled = true;
  }
  content.innerText = `Step Number ${currentStep}`;
});

finishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  location.reload();
});
```

```css
#stepProgressBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.step {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.step-text {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.bullet {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.bullet.completed {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
}

.bullet.completed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  display:flex;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 20px;  
}


/* Base styles and helper stuff */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 250ms background-color;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="stepProgressBar">
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Super Duper Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Long Long Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Loooong Title</p>
      <div class="bullet">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
      <p class="step-text">Title</p>
      <div class="bullet ">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <p id="content" class="text-center">Step Number 1</p>
    <button id="previousBtn" class="hidden"></button>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    <button id="finishBtn" class="hidden">Finish</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated my question. Can it be without javascript? I mean just the css can make it works regardless number of steppers.

Comment: Because I tried to remove the js part from the answer you given, the lines become shorter.

Comment: I do not see that issue when I try removing the js, so I don't know how to help with that. I did nothing to modify your js except to match the MAX_STEPS to the number of `.step` elements in your html, which just sets the end point of the program. Also, there are no styles being modified in your js, so I don't know why you are experiencing an altered display of your lines when it is removed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cwhxLdre/
I changed from 7 steps to 3 steps and you can see all the lines break.